# where is the best way to add a mandatory "internet connection" in android studio (java)?

Tags: java, android-studio

My problem is: IF I restart my device, it is possible to play to my app without internet connection even with my java code with an internet connection MANDATORY, so I don't understand why !?
Nevertheless, If I connect my device only "once" to internet, so after that, if I want to play to my app, I need absolutely internet to play to my app to make disapear the dialog window " OUPS, NO INTERNET CONNECTION ! RETRY ? " !

So, where is the best way to fix that please ? add permission in the manifest ? add some line in the MAIN ACTIVITY ? I don't understand where is the problem ?  thanks a lot...

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: it's already done !

Answer (score 1):

Even if you request Internet access permission in the manifest, that permission only means that your app is allowed to go online, not that the app ever actually will go online. You've probably noticed that your end user can still start and use your app while Airplane Mode is active.

What you actually want to do is to directly check network availability using [ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) and make all functionality unavailable if you detect that the network is unavailable.

```
myNetworkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onAvailable(Network network)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnavailable()
    {
        // warn user that network is unavailable and refuse to do stuff
    }
}
```

Note: This code applies to Android 10 (API 29+). If you're targeting an older API level, see the official doc that I linked for examples.